# Can this contour integral be computed in closed form?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Our tutor gave us some contour integrals to write in closed form (not homework, just exercise), which we never discussed. I still wonder about the following:

$$
\oint_C \frac{dz}{f(z) - a}
$$

Is there a closed form for this integral (something general only depending on $f$ and $a$ and $C$)?

The reason I ask is because I think there is a mistake in the question (at least in what I wrote) and that there might be no simple form. I think what the question should be is

$$
\oint_C \frac{f'(z) dz}{f(z) - a}
$$

for which I think I know the result ($g(z) = f(z) - a$ and then the argument principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $z_1, \dots, z_n$ are the points in the interior of the contour such that $f(z_i) = a$. (I'll assume that $f(z)$ is never equal to $a$ on the contour itself. Since the zeroes of non-constant holomorphic functions are isolated, and since the contour plus its interior is compact, there are only finitely many such $z_i$'s, by Bolzano-Weierstrass.)

I'm going to assume that $f(z) - a$ has *simple zeroes* at $z_1, \dots, z_n$. (I'm sure there is a generalisation to the case where some of the zeroes are of higher multiplicity, but I haven't thought this through.)

Notice that Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ around $z = z_i$ takes the form,
$$ f(z) = a + f'(z_i) (z - z_i) + \dots $$
Therefore, the residue of the meromorphic function $1/(f(z) - a)$ at $z_i$ is
$$ {\rm Res}_{z = z_i} \frac 1 {f(z) - a} = \frac 1 {f'(z_i)}.$$

Hence, by the residue theorem,
$$ \oint_C \frac{dz}{f(z) - a} = 2\pi i \sum_{i} \frac 1 {f'(z_i)}.$$

Comment: If some zero of $f(z)-a$ has higher multiplicity, then the residue of $\frac{1}{f(z)-a}$ at that zero will vanish. So you can get away with only summing over its simple zeroes...

Comment: @ Micah I didn't know this! :-) How would you prove this?

Comment: Maybe for higher order through long division you see that there are no terms $(z-z_0)^{-1}$

Comment: Never mind, what I wrote is nonsense (or at least not even remotely obvious). I agree that one ought to be able to use long division to write the residue in terms of $f$'s derivatives, but the actual form it takes is probably messy.

Comment: This is good! Thank you! I did not think this would be connected to residue theorem, but it makes sense.

Comment: @Micah, assuming that $f(z)-a$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$then we can write $f(z)-a = (z-z_0)^m g(z) $ where $g$ is nonzero then $1/g$ is analytic in a nbhd of $z_0$

$$\frac{1}{f(z)-a} = \frac{1}{(z-z_0)^m} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k$$

Hence it seems that depending on the constants $a_k$ the residue might not be zero.